# <h2> and img in one line

Tags: templates, html

```
<span><img src='/img/Rosia.gif' /><h2>Россия</h2></span>
```

how can i set image in one line with h2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add the style display:inline; to the h2.

```
<span><img src='/img/Rosia.gif' /><h2 style='display:inline;'>Россия</h2></span>
```